# NFC with URL and information for the server written on it

Tags: php, nfc

Currently I'm trying to make a system, that uses NFC tags to determine if a client has arrived at a specified location.

My current solution is quite simple and easily fooled. The NFC tag has an URL with GET information on it ( service.domain/index.php?location=1 ). And can easily be replicated by a person just typing in the correct URL by hand.

So what I'm thinking is I need some way for the NFC tag to hold a unique and 'not so easy to access' key, that get's submitted to server, when said URL is opened in the browser. Similar to how a Form on a page generates POST data, that isn't visible to the user.

The documentation on such things is scarce on the web at present, so I'm hoping someone here can provide a solution. It can be virtually any kind of solution as long as it sticks to the principle of working through the users internet browser, when he puts his device ( NFC reader, phone, etc. ) up against the NFC tag.

Comment: So the idea of identifying at a location is by swiping your phone over a device, and using NFC you would transmit certain credentials that would identify your user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a job for a digital signature.

Instead of writing:

```
service.domain/index.php?location=1
```

onto your tag, you can write something like this:

```
service.domain/index.php?location=1&nonce=some-number&sig=some-base64-string
```

The idea is, that you append a acending nonce number to the URL. The nonce number should not be re-used and ascending. You build a digital signature over this URL and append it.

Only you have the private key to generate a valid signature. Each reader location may however have the public key that is used to check the validity of the signature. This makes the URL tamper proof, e.g. noone will be able to build a valid url by just modifying the location.

An attacker is still able to make a copy of this URL and write it to a different tag. He can't neither change the nonce, the signature or the location however. If you keep track of the nonce values and ivalidate them after use (by rewriting the tag with a new nonce and a new signature) you can detect attempts to fool the system with copies.

You can also add the UID to the signature calculation. That makes attacking a bit harder because if an attacker wants to make a copy he would also have to clone the UID (possible, but that requires quite a bit of know-how).

It's not perfectly secure but to hack this system requires quite a bit of criminal energy and effort.

If you use such a system I suggest to use elliptic curve digital signatures because their signature is quite small and should fit even onto small tags.

Comment: This is a good start, but probably the biggest problem is the 'rewriting the tags' part to put new URLs on them. Since I've got quite a few locations and tags. The UID addition to the signatures generation certainly seems like the best option. And I'll probably end up doing a combination of the 2, so even if an attacker makes duplicates, he'll have to start over in a few days, when I've done a regular tag re-write.